# Laravel user edit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have user details from DB and print using blade loop with button for edit. now I want, if I click button I need user details for the button which is clicked for user.

i tried with hidden input filed `<input type="hidden" value="{{$user->email}}" name="email">` 
in my controller I just print the value from form submit. but I am getting only last user.

See below, I hope you will understand..

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        <form action="{!!url('/delete')!!}" method="post"> {!!csrf_field()!!}   
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                   @foreach($users as $user)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>   <input type="hidden" value="{{$user->email}}" name="email">
                        <td>{{$user->role}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="edit"  >Edit</button>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="delete"    >Delete</button>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="make"  >Make Admin</button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>  
        </form>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to go to edit page with a user's details when you click edit button.

```
<a href="{{ route('your_route_name',$user->id) }}" class="test-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because you are using same name "email" for all user's hidden field. It is getting overridden, since form is same . 
Instead, add the `form` tag inside your loop and remove the one before table.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <form action="{!!url('/delete')!!}" method="post"> {!!csrf_field()!!}
      <tr>
        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>   <input type="hidden" value="{{$user->email}}" name="email">
        <td>{{$user->role}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="edit"  >Edit</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="delete"    >Delete</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="make"  >Make Admin</button>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
@endforeach
```

Or, you can put a single hidden email field outside your loop and assign it's value using JS before submitting.
Step 1: Add data attribute (`data-email`) to your buttons to get email. Also add a common class name to capture click event. (See JS part)

```
<button type="button" class="test-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="edit"  data-email="{{$user->email}}" >Edit</button>
<button type="button" class="test-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="delete" data-email="{{$user->email}}"  >Delete</button>
<button type="button" class="test-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="make"  data-email="{{$user->email}}" >Make Admin</button>
```

Step 2: Move `email` hidden field outside the loop with value as blank.

```
<form action="{!!url('/delete')!!}" method="post" id="test-form"> {!!csrf_field()!!} 
<input type="hidden" value="" name="email" id="email">
```

Step 3: Add JS to capture click event on the buttons and assign the value of the clicked button's email to the email text field.

```
$(".test-btn ").on("click",function(e){
    //assign the email value from button to variable
    email = $(this).attr(data-email);

    //assign the email value to email hidden field
    $("#email").value(email);

    //submit the form
    $("#test-form").submit();
});
```